# css footer-link can't able to adjust at the bottom in html5

Tags: css, html

This is my code for footer part:

```
  <footer>
     <div class="footer">
        <nav class="footer-nav">
           <ul class="list-1">
              <li><img src="img/notes.png" alt="" /></li>
              <li>ARTICLES</li>
              <li>COLUMNS</li>
              <li>BLOG</li>
              <li>TOPICS</li>
           </ul>
           <ul class="list-2">
              <li>ABOUT</li>
              <li>AUTHORS</li>
              <li>MASTHEAD</li>
              <li>CONTRUBUTE</li>
              <li>STYLE GUIDE</li>
              <li>CONTACT</li>
              <li>SPONSORSHIPS</li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
        <hr >
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <img class="col-md-6-pgf" src="img/footer1.png" /> 
              <h3 class="footer-title">.NET Training</h3>
              <p class="footer-pgf">Less of boring theory! Hands on programming isour training methidology! You'll love it.</p>
              <a class="footer-link-1" href="#">learn more ></a> 
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <img class="col-md-6-pgf" src="img/footer2.png" /> 
              <h3 class="footer-title">Shopify Expert at $20/hour</h3>
              <p class="footer-pgf">Unique custom made shopify theme and tweaks. Strat selling online with stunning eCommerce storefronts created using the shopify CMS</p>
              <a class="footer-link-2" href="#">learn more ></a>                
           </div>
        </div>
        <hr >
        <div >
           <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2013 Dot Net How</p>
        </div>
     </div>
  </footer>
```

And this is css:

```
.footer-pgf{
    font-size:11px; 
    width: 86%;
}
.footer-title{
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.footer{
    clear:both;
    background:url('../img/footer-bg.jpg');
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer-nav .list-1 {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align: center; 
}
.footer-nav .list-2 {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align: center; 
}
.footer-nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    padding:8px;
}
.footer-link{

padding-top:10px;   

}
```

So my page look like this in footer part: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bybvB.jpg

I tried to adjust the footer-link-1 in footer, but can't able to do it.

May i know, What is my mistake, and how to fix this.

Comment: create fiddle for better suggestions. In your question you shows only the part of HTML and CSS. Check it http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/re998qws/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to anchor the link to the bottom of the left side image, an apparent fix is to give `.footer-pgf` the height equivalent of four lines: `4em + 4 * (line-height - 1)`. Plug in your actual line-height, of course.

But the underlying design decision to align fluid text content to static content introduces more questions. How should the design react if the text content wraps to five or more lines? What happens if the end-user's browser window is skinnier? What happens if the image is replaced with a taller or shorter one? How likely are these things going to occur?

Comment: In essence, put a hight style on `.footer-pgf` that pushes the link down to where you want it.